# AsyncTask to populate ListView with Custom in doInBackgroud

Tags: java, android

I want ask your opinion about this code

```
 public class showDataLunar extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Forecast>, Void, LunarAdapter> {

 protected LunarAdapter doInBackground(ArrayList<Forecast>... passing) {
        ArrayList<Forecast> data = passing[0];
        if(data==null) return null;
        return new LunarAdapter(ctx, R.layout.adapter_lunar, data);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(LunarAdapter result) {
        if(result!=null) listLunar.setAdapter(result);
    }
 }
```

This code works fine, in my app there are at startup 3 `ListView`s with image and more, this make a little bit slow open the app so I try this.

I create the `Adapter` in background then, passing it to `onPostExecute`, I set the `Adapter` in my list.

It works fine, probably in this way I can't notify data changes to change `View` but in my case I don't need to do it.

It's faster, but is it correct ? I need some opinions

Comment: Basically, UI Updates must be done on Main Thread, while intensive and network tasks must be done in background, so i could think that is ok

Comment: why do you think that *it is faster*?

Comment: *I need some opinions* the Balkan Towel Snap, the Spanish Wet Willy, the Croatian Purple Nurple (sorry, could not resist)

Comment: Because on device low end activity (with 3 listview) keeps less time to show

Comment: To be clear, when I said "it's faster" I mean that it's faster to show activity, total time doesn't change, the users experience it's better (for me).

Comment: What you are doing in `doInBackground` should be run on the UI thread. Post the constructor for LunarAdapter. Whatever is slowing your app down is most likely not coming from the code you posted.